# Firefox asks to install flash, then plugin finder says "no suitable plugins were found."

Tags: firefox, flash

Every time I visit a site that contains a Flash object, the Firefox plugin finder asks me to install Flash, but when I click to install it, it reports that "No suitable plugins were found." I know I can install Flash manually using `apt-get` or something, but how can I get Firefox to do what it's apparently supposed to do here?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that flash is not working properly with Firefox. First of all I suggest you to install flash with:

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Then if it's not OK, try to reset your Firefox.
You have to go to

`Firefox --> Troubleshooting Information --> Reset Firefox...`

Comment: @Jon, this will install the old flash player 11.2 for npapi browser like firefox. If you want to use latest flash player 15 in linux you should switch to google chrome, or install google-chrome's flashplugin for chromium